# How do I recode an XML document in XMLSpy to use entities

Tags: character-encoding, recode, altova, xmlspy

I have a rather large XSLT template which contains bilingual text (national characters in UTF-8). I am looking for a function that will recode all `CDATA` elements inside to use XML `#` entities, allowing me to store the XSLT as plain `US-ASCII` encoding.

Here is a basic example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>Soirée</test>
```

where `é` is encoded as `C3 A9`. The desired output would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<test>Soir&#233;e</test>
```

where `&#233;` corresponds to the codepoint for `'LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE' (U+00E9)`. Changing the encoding preamble on the first example results in an error as the UTF-8 bytes become invalid.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to resort to a macro?

Comment: "Changing the encoding preamble…": Yes, the declaration is descriptive (what is), not prescriptive (what to make it).  You should be able to let a tool or library write the encoding declaration based on the encoding it was directed to use. So, "how" is the question but for XML Spy, I don't know the answer. (Of course, you could use an XSLT on your XSLT file.)

Comment: For now I am using an XSLT `copy @*|node()` with an output encoding of `US-ASCII`.